# How to know that a specfic incoming sms is a reply to a previous outgoing sms?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am integrating Twilio SMS service where my users are able to send SMS messages to their clients. I would like to be able to link each reply with the sent SMS. In another word, is there any field in the Message Resource that could lead me to conclude whether the incoming message received is related to the outgoing message my user sent previously ? I need same behavior as Email send/reply functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way to do this I’m afraid, the SMS protocol has no information about users replying to a specific message. SMS is chronological, you can test this by opening your phone’s SMS app and trying to reply to the second to last message you received from someone. In SMS there’s no way to do that.

The best thing you can do is consider the messages chronologically, and assume that the reply is in response to the last message you sent to that number from the number you sent it from.

I suspect your are interested in this because you need to send notifications and get responses to those notifications and you realised you might need to send more than one notification to a user at a time but still get their responses. The best way to get around this is to use different numbers to send the different notification messages from, then when they reply you can tell which notification they were replying to by the number they sent the message to.